# Phonegap childbrowser plugin getting last page redirection

Tags: events, plugins, cordova

Hy everybody!

I'm trying to use Childbrowser Phonegap plugin to redirect the user within my phonegap application for user Twitter authentication. The idea is to detect when twitter redirects to callback page, get oauth_verifier token and finally get the request token.

The question is that it seems that twitter makes a redirection to api/authentication and then other redirection to the callback url. Anyone knows how can I jump over the first onLocationChanged event and then capture the last redirection? Can I wait for twitter to finish the whole redirection and finally get the last redirection?

Thanks in advance!

Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a blog post and tutorial about this exact thing - 
[www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=40](http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=40)

The piece you would be most interested in is. this will allow you to listen for multiple changes but only fire when the callback URL is called.

```
if (loc.indexOf("http://www.YOUR_DOMAIN.com/?") >= 0){

}
```

Comment: Thank you Drew!
I've downloaded your sample and it's very similar to my code.
I've found my problem and it was that I was using a fake url (i,e: http://localhost/twitter?....) and in iOS the webview is not redirected if the page does not exists. I've tried the same code in android and it works ok. To figure out this problem, I've used other active page and it's works.

Cheers!